# Onesignal "Apns Delegate Never Fired" while using Firebase Auth with and without swizzling

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I have issue with OneSignal push notifications for iOS app after I added Firebase Auth with phone. All iOS devices listed in OneSignal are marked with "Apns Delegate Never Fired" label and notifications can be sended but app don't receive them.

I found two similar issues that

- https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/790
- https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/245

As I understand the problem might be with swizzling that is used by Firebase Auth.
I disabled swizzling using info.plist file as it suggested in the [official firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling). But issue remains, so I think that I am missing something and OneSignal SDK still not being called.

My AppDelegate file looks like

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
           Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
 }

 override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

           if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
               completionHandler(.noData)
               return
           }
}
```

Comment: Please check this solution for the similar problem you have posted above. https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases/tag/3.2.0

Comment: @SHASHANK what is the solution? I am using latest SDK already